# Hide post when ACF custom date field has passed

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables

I'm trying to adjust some code I've used in he past to allow for a specific user role. When the custom post type for an event passes a certain date (ACF field) the post is no longer visible.

```
<section class="first-event">
    <div class="container px-5 px-sm-0">
        
        <?php

        if (current_user_can('stallholder')) 
            $today = date('Ymd', strtotime("-10 days"));
        else
            $today = date('Ymd');

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => array( 'product' ),
            'posts_per_page' => '1',
            'meta_key' => 'event_start_date',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
            // only display if custom date hasn't passed
            'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'event_end_date',
                      'value' => $today,
                      'compare' => '>=',
                      'type' => 'numeric'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'event_end_date',
                      'value' => '',
                      'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ),
        );

        // The Query
        $events_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

            <?php while ( $events_query->have_posts() ) { $events_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="row g-0" style="background-color:<?php the_field('event_colour'); ?>">



                <div class="<?php $categories = get_the_category(get_the_id()); foreach ($categories as $category) {echo $category->slug.' '; }?>" id="content-wide">

                    <article class="events-wrapper">

                    <a class="link-wrap" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"></a>

                        <div class="row g-0 align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-md-6 g-0 order-2 order-md-1">
                                <div class="events-body">
                                    <h3><?php the_field('event_title'); ?></h3>
                                    <ul id="event-info">
                                        <li class="small-title">Date<span class="colon-space">: </span></br><span><?php the_field('date'); ?></span></li>
                                        <li class="small-title">Location<span class="colon-space">: </span></br><span><?php the_field('location'); ?></span></li>
                                        <li class="small-title">Price<span class="colon-space">: </span></br><span><?php the_field('price'); ?></span></li>
                                    </ul>   
                                    <?php the_excerpt();?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6 g-0 order-1 order-md-2">
                                
                                <div class="events-image" style="background-image: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>')"><?php the_post_thumbnail('3:2');?></div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                </div>
        </div>

            <?php } ?>

    </div>
</section>
```

What I'm trying achieve is when a specific user role (stallholder) is logged in the event is hidden 10 days prior.

NB. When I tried just implementing $today = date('Ymd', strtotime("-10 days")); on it's own and not in an if statement it didn't work either.

Comment: You compare the event end date as a numeric type value. The format of $today is Ymd which is a string... Have you tried to use the timestamp (u) of the date ? It should work better. Don't forget to convert it as a int (intval)